# Using if / else result alias inside WHERE clause in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns:

`user_id`, `parent_id`

And I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN parent_id IS NOT NULL 
         THEN parent_id 
         ELSE user_id 
   END) as id
   FROM users
   WHERE id in (43, 23, 11, 277);
```

But it doesn't work - it says that the id column cannot be found. How can I make it use that `alias` within the `where` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, a column alias defined in the `SELECT` cannot be used in the `WHERE`.  You can repeat the expression or use a subquery.  MySQL also offers another solution:  MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause, so it can be used in this situation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(parent_id, user_id) as id
FROM users
HAVING id in (43, 23, 11, 277);
```

This will not work in other databases.  It can be highly convenient in MySQL, particularly when you have complex expressions in the `SELECT`.  (In other databases, you would use a subquery or CTE with no performance penalty).

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. My actual SQL query is quite complex, with 2 subqueries and 3 joins in total, and explaining the whole query would take ages, so I provided a small, shortened one that was direct to the issue. `HAVING` keyword solved my problem, so I will accept this answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` was made for that. It returns the first non-NULL value.

```
SELECT coalesce(parent_id, user_id) as id
FROM users
WHERE coalesce(parent_id, user_id) in (43, 23, 11, 277);
```

And since you can't use an alias in the  `where` clause - you have to use it twice.

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

Comment: This is a nice approach as well. However, for this particular issue, `HAVING` was more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

in where clause we can't make the alias so you can use column name in condition

```
SELECT IFNULL(parent_id, user_id) as id
FROM users
WHERE IFNULL(parent_id, user_id) IN (43, 23, 11, 277);
```